# bitmobin Streaming url video casting issue via DLNA service

Tags: casting, video-streaming, dlna, bitmovin-player

when we used bitmovin video platform for streaming URL to cast on a smart tv . The streaming url is performing well with other services and do not cast via DLNA service

I tried to use static url but that is also not working

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend contacting the Bitmovin Support team, or at least post this in the [Bitmovin Community](https://community.bitmovin.com/).

It would also be helpful to know which error you're seeing (if any), which device you try to cast to, which Bitmovin Products you're using (Streams, Live Encoder, VOD Encoder, Playback), versions of it, ... What have you tried so far?

I know this isn't an answer to your problem, but with the little details you provided I don't think anyone will be able to help with your specific problem.